# Class Inheritance or Single Table Inheritance in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I have the following scenario and I'm not sure if I should use Class Inheritance or Single Table Inheritance:

```
Class User
  has_one :main_list
  has_one :known_list
  has_many :regular_lists
end

Class List
  has_many :words
end

Class Word
  belongs_to :list
end
```

What I would like to do is have each different list type be a different class, the problem is that if I do that, I would need to add `main_list_id`, `known_list_id`, and `regular_list_id` to the `Word` object/class.  This seems cumbersome.  Can I do something like:

```
Class MainList
  has_many :words, :foreign_key => list_id
end
```

and then something like:

`@user.main_list.find_by_name("MainList")` ?

The only problem with this is that someone could name a `RegularList` "MainList".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :lists
end

Class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :words
end

Class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end
```

On the list class you could add two boolean fields to list; one for main_list and the other for known_list.  On that class you could also add validations to make sure that each user only has one main list and one known list.  To select the main list for a user you could do:

```
@user.lists.find(:first, :conditions => {:main_list => true})
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but what about doing @user.regular_lists now?  Isn't that going to return all the lists including the main_list and known_list?  Would an index on these boolean fields be appropriate?

Comment: To find those, it would be @user.lists.find(:first, :conditions => {:main_list => false, :known_list => false}).  You could also simplify this by creating named scopes.  And no, it would not be a good idea to index the boolean fields... just index the user_id.

Comment: Edit for above: the query should be @user.lists.find(:all, :conditions => {:main_list => false, :known_list => false}) since there are multiple regular lists...  Sorry about that.